# Is it possible to load a background image via attribute with CSS?

Tags: css, css-content

I was wondering, if I could use CSS to load a background if the attribute gets a specific class. To demonstrate, it should load on `hover`.

**HTML**

```
<div id="testdiv" title="http://www.thesearchagents.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/Google-Search.jpg">hover me...</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#testdiv {
    line-height:100px;
}    
#testdiv:hover {
    outline:3px solid red;
    background:url(attr(title)) 100%; // > How can I make this work?
}

#testdiv:hover:after {
    content:attr(title); // > This works fine...
}
```

[<kbd>**JS Fiddle**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/75Ss9/)

---

Unfortunately, no background image shows up on mouseover (hover).

**(How) can I make this work?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory, yes:

```
background-image: attr(title url);
```

That `url` is a keyword telling the browser to interpret the title attribute as a URL value.

Unfortunately, such usage is experimental at best, and not supported in any major browser yet.

So currently, the answer is no, you cannot do that. Which is a shame.